# How can I support many sortable fields in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement to query data but sort by different fields (probably more than 30).
I know I can build a secondary index and use different field as sort key in different GSI. However, it will exceed the maximum gsi one table can have.

Is there a pattern to restructure the data to make it sortable via a single GSI or even without GSI?

The data I need to support looks like:

```
Table: OrderProductUser

# Order Items:
type
createdDate
updatedDate
amount (number)
fee (number)
tax (number)

# Product Items:
type
name
price
...

# User Items:

type
firstName
lastName
dob
gender
...

...
```

Since Dynamodb recommends using one table, I put all different records into one. The `type` field in each row indicates what the row is.

But I'd like to support sort on all different fields including string, date and number. If I sort them in application, it won't support pagination very well. Is there a patten to support that?

Comment: 30+ secondary indexes would be challenging (and somewhat unusual) for any DB. Is it the case that you need to query on a smaller subset of attributes, but then finally sort by amount, fee, tax etc. that could be done locally?

Comment: I seems to me that regular relational database would be more suited for your case. Any specific reason you choose DynamoDB for your scenario?

Comment: @jarmod The reason I can't do local sort is that I need to support pagination which is hard to do locally.

Comment: @Marcin In regular relational database, I can save different data in different table. I chose Dynamodb for serverless application since it has a better performance and scalability. However, as I move more data into the one table, I need to build more GSI to sort different fields.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao There is limit of 20 GSI. So if you plan on using them all, it will cost you a lot, as each GSI has its own costs.

Comment: Yep I understand that. If they are sparse index, then it only costs on the real usage.

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 GSI per table...as you can overload them

simply concatenate the attribute name to the GSI Partition or Sort key...
ex.

```
Partition    Sort
AMOUNT       99.99
FEE          1.50
xxx          AMOUNT:00099.99
xxx          FEE:001.50
```

But you'll only be able to sort by one column at a time, and you have to write multiple records out to DDB.

Given the limitation of sorting/filtering in DDB, a standard RDS is likely a better choice for a high functioning UI.

The usual recommendation is to front DDB with ElasticSearch... and if you truly need the kind of scaling DDB+ElasticSearch can provide, then go for it.

But for most users, RDS Aurora for instance is much more cost effective.